TLS Null Ciphers in Go
I'm currently implementing a TLS client in go. Unfortunately, the TLS Server is only supporting a NULL cipher. The Server is not under my control, so I cannot change that.
As can be seen in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go Go has no NULL ciphers implemented.

Why are there no NULL ciphers in Go? I know they are insecure. But Go has also a list of insecure ciphers, that can be activated manually.

How can I add a new custom cipher to my client? Is that possible without forking or vendoring?



"Why" is probably a question answerable only by the developers of that library. Note that the NULL cipher is not supported at all in TLS 1.3, so getting rid of it seems ok. It's probably best to include only the last question in your question to make it more focused.

See Here about tls config https://github.com/haoel/mTLS/blob/0ee2a65200d1ce3a49ab43f074995dcb216d1f08/server.go#L84 how to set ciphers

When the server only supports NULL chipers, the questions is what is this for a shit why implement TLS without chipers

That kind of hardware is only be used locally, where nobody can be physically present to intercept traffic. Also the traffic is not really secret and the hardware is too weak for encryption (the traffic will notably be slowed down). The only thing that is needed is authenticity. That's why certificates are being used.

I found there is a package providing OpenSSL bindings for Go. I'm thinkging if I can achieve it using that package: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl
